# Производительность jQuery в Хроме

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, производительность

Отвечая на один из [вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/456031/), наткнулся на интересную штуку. Решил протестировать написанные функции на [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/getsibling/2). Проверял три версии на списке из 500 элементов, при поиске соседей медианы списка.

Vanilla JS раз:

```
function getSiblingsByChilds(element) {
    var out = element.parentNode.childNodes;
    out = Array.prototype.filter.call(out, function(e) {
        return (e.nodeType == 1 && e == element) ? false : true;
    });

    return out;
}
```

Vanilla JS два:

```
function getSiblings(elem) {
    var siblings = [];
    var sibling = elem;
    while (sibling.previousSibling) {
        sibling = sibling.previousSibling;
        sibling.nodeType == 1 && siblings.push(sibling);
    }

    sibling = elem;
    while (sibling.nextSibling) {
      sibling = sibling.nextSibling;
      sibling.nodeType == 1 && siblings.push(sibling);
    }

    return siblings;
}
```

И jQuery `.siblings()`, который представляет из себя, если посмотреть в исходники:

```
sibling: function( n, elem ) {
    var matched = [];

    for ( ; n; n = n.nextSibling ) {
        if ( n.nodeType === 1 && n !== elem ) {
            matched.push( n );
        }
    }

    return matched;
}
```

Так вот, почему в Хроме (в Мозилле и даже в IE11 всё ожидаемо) результаты гораздо круче у jQuery, чем у нативного JS? Может быть я просто где-то ошибся? Или просто не правильно интерпретирую результаты тестирования (признаюсь не умею тестировать)?

Comment: Там же только в Chrome победил JQ, в остальных сильно выделился нативный JS. Чем выше -> тем лучше.

Comment: @ThisMan, а Вам не кажется это странным? В этом и состоит мой вопрос, почему в Хроме так получается.

Answer (score 1):

1. Не знаю, откуда ты взял такой jQuery-код, он похож на первый, но `n` должно быть первым потомком родителя `elem`.
2. В первом коде filter медленнее цикла. А так, это должен быть самый быстрый вариант.
3. Ещё в первом надо условный оператор выкинуть. Тоже только зря время тратит.
4. А почему в jsperf исключение происходит?

   > Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined.
   >
   > message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
   >   fileName: http://jsperf.com/benchmark-47.js
   >   lineNumber: 21

Comment: 1. С [исходников](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js), `siblings()` -> `sibling()`. 2 и 3 не думаю, что оно на *столько* влияет. 4. Вероятно из-за того, что они пытаются использовать java для подсчета времени, а она немного блокируется.

Comment: @Rolandius, добавил немного тестов: http://jsperf.com/getsibling/2

Comment: Всё равно нативный JS *медленнее*, в Мозилле вообще кардинально отличаются результаты. Странно это. Видимо прикол Gecko какой-то.